# What should be the global ignore pattern for eclipse settings

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

```
module/.settings/org.eclipse.jdt.core.prefs
module/.settings/org.eclipse.wst.common.component
module/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
```

What should be the global ignore pattern for eclipse settings. If I use .settings or META-INF in TortoiseSVN global ignore pattern, it doesn't seem to pick it. What wild card should I use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends a bit on what you mean by "it doesn't pick it up". I just did a test on my system, adding `.settings META-INF` to the end of my global ignore list in TortoiseSVN Settings. The first thing I saw was that the icon overlays still appeared, with question marks, on those directories when viewed in Windows Explorer. One might naturally assume then that the items were not correctly specified in the global ignore list. But, in fact, one would be wrong :-) If that is the problem you saw, there is an easy fix, and you have two options.

**Option 1: Do nothing.**

TortoiseSVN has honored your request where it counts (just not with the icon overlays). That is, if you open the **Commit** dialog or the **Check for Modifications** dialog and select "show unversioned files", you will *not* see .settings, META-INF, or their descendants. Likely TortoiseSVN will eventually re-sync the icon overlays to be correct as well.

**Option 2: Run SVN >> Clean Up on the parent directory.**

This should resync your icon overlays on demand so it will show you the same information as the other dialogs mentioned above.

If you are seeing a different symptom, please add some further details to your problem statement.